# SQL Inner Join multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question for my application, that uses MySQL. I have a table with products and another with the media from the products (with photos, videos, etc.) - that has a multiples itens from products. That table has a FK with the ID of the product.

I need to load a product with all the media (that is multiple registries). Which is the best way to to this?

I tried with the INNER JOIN but it receives the registries multiple times with the products duplicated (because I have multiples media itens). I think that is not the best way.

Comment: can you show us the query that you tried, and the output that you expect?

Comment: According to your vague description, `INNER JOIN` retrieves the expected output (and will omit products that have no media). What exactly do you want to accomplish and what do you have so far?

Comment: I want a better way to do this. Is this right, for performance?

Comment: if you wanna list all media then yes, this is the right way... if you want just a count of product's media then you would need a group by

Comment: I think you must use inner join because it will check multiple entries. And you can then "group by" product id. So you will never get `multiple times with the products duplicated`

Answer (score 0):

Examples of the data and results you are getting would be helpful.

But, based on what I can glean from your question so far, I think your problem will be solved by a simple addition of DISTINCT.

e.g. Instead of SELECT ProductId, ProductName, MediaId, MediaName... do SELECT DISTINCT ProductId, ProductName, MediaId, MediaName

Without the distinct, you get all linked rows between the two tables. With the DISTINCT, you will get only *unique combinations* of the fields selected.